# How to separate locked areas?

Tags: interface

If you move an area to match up with another area, the get "locked" and I can't figure out how to separate them without joining and splitting a new area.

You can see that at the beginning the areas are separate, but at the end they are locked:

[image]

Comment: It seems to be made as intended. I don't think it is useful in most cases, either. Good question. I'm also waiting for a possible answer. :}

Comment: @LeonCheung It is useful for joining areas that don't share a complete edge, however it's really annoying when they get locked by accident and I have to redo my layout..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For easy understanding, let's just call the areas in your image as "Left" and "Right"; and "Middle" for the new split area:

---

### **A Three-click Way:**

1. Right Click on the border of the *right* area;
2. Choose "**Split Area**", move the mouse to the area you want to split;
3. Click and drag on the little triangle at the upper-right corner of the *left* area towards the *middle* area, to join them as a new one. Release the mouse button.

As shown below:

[image]

---

### **A Two-Click Way:**

1. Click and drag on the little triangle at the upper-right corner of the *left* area;
2. Click and drag on the little triangle at the upper-right corner of the *middle* area towards to the *right* area, then turn back to left. Release the mouse button.

[image]

Comment: Good answer, Leon. Glad to know there is a way to un-stick it, but there really ought to be a "Separate" or "Unlock" option in the Area Options contextual menu when you right click on a four-window intersection. I think a right-click is the first thing people try when they get stuck like this. If any devs are reading this, please consider adding it. :-)

Comment: I think there are already a UI refactor project going out there. Let's pray to see that soon. :)