# How do I create a right column when I have a 2-rows layout?

Tags: interface, workflow, customization

Suppose I have 2 windows under the following layout:

```
 _____
|_____|
|_____|
```

How do I create a right window so that it becomes:

```
_________
|_____| |
|_____|_|
```

Without disturbing the open ones?

Comment: In your ascii art you change the total size of the window. Is this intended? Or are there other surrounding editors that are not shown?

Comment: It is not intended, sorry. Edited. You already solved the issue anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the two editors separately, but make sure the splits align vertically:

[image]

Note that once the vertical splits are aligned, [they become locked](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5637/599).

I actually wrote a [feature request](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Proposals/UI/Area_Splitting) on the wiki a while ago asking to improve this behavior.

Comment: May I just ask you an additional question, so I don't need to make another one? If I have three windows in a row, and a single window on top of those 3, how is it possible to remove that upper window?

Comment: @Dokkat Unfortunately no, not directly. But there is a workaround which works in some situations. Generally asking more than one question per post is discouraged, but you are encouraged to ask as many questions as you have (for related questions you can include a link to the related post). Could you ask this as a separate question with a screenshot of your screen layout? Thanks :)